# Куда делась буква i

Tags: python, list

На выходе нужно получить из строки

> Python is best I love python

Строку:
**Python is best I love**

Но получаю:
**Python is best love**

Код:

```
txt = list(map(str, input().split()))
string = " "
for i in txt:
    if i.lower() not in string.lower():
        string += i + " "
print(string)
```

upd кажется, что это из-за функции lower()

Comment: Слово `I` состоит из одной буквы, которая уже есть в слове `is`, поэтому проверка не проходит

Comment: Python is best I love

Comment: Гораздо проще так: `''.join([i for i in txt.split().lower() if i not in set(txt.split().lower())])`. Хотя кому как...

Comment: @Глеб создавать set в каждой итерации как-то неоптимально

Comment: @Глеб а ещё это не работает, потому что у списков нет метода lower )

Comment: @andreymal, да, с lower() я как-то не подумал, надо было вставить `[i.lower() for i in ...]`. А почему set создается в каждой итерации? Ведь итерируемый объект не изменяется, зачем же его "переделывать"?

Comment: @Глеб задавать вопросы «зачем» нет смысла, просто питон так работает, и это факт, с которым мы должны как-то жить

Answer (score 3):

Заведите вспомогательное множество, куда будете складывать встретившиеся слова, и сверяйте с ним.
Также, лучше использовать метод [str.casefold()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) для регистронезависимого сравнения, чем `str.lower()`.
Для оптимизации кода использован ["моржовый" оператор :=](https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/555924/)

```
txt = 'Python is best I love python'.split()

string, used_words = '', set()
for i in txt:
    if (word := i.casefold()) not in used_words:
        string += i + ' '
        used_words.add(word)
print(string)
```

```
Python is best I love
```

Comment: В данном случае это не критично, но, к примеру, `'ß'.casefold()` даст `ss`. В некоторых случаях это может дать неожиданный результат.

Answer (score 3):

Вы, наверно, хотели избавиться от повторяющихся **слов**, а не букв.

Значит, вместо

```
if i.lower() not in string.lower():
```

вы хотели

```
if i.lower() not in string.lower().split():
```

разбивая таким образом (до сих пор собранную) строку `string` (временно) обратно в список **слов**, чтобы тестировать, если очередное **слово** пока еще не находится в списке **слов**.

---

*Примечание:*

- Вместо постепенного формирования результата путем `string += i + " "`,
- вы могли подходящие слова собирать в списке, напр. с именем `unique_words`,
- и затем из него сразу же одной командой `" ".join(unique_words)` получить результат — целое предложение.

Answer (score 2):

Вижу себе решение Вашей задачи приблизительно так

```py
txt_orig = 'Python is best I love python'

control_txt = txt_orig.lower().split()
words = txt_orig.split()

u_words = ' '.join(
    words[i] 
    for i in range(len(words)) 
    if control_txt[i] not in control_txt[:i]
)

print(u_words)
```

---

```latex
Python is best I love
```

---

#### Ну и так, с небольшим извратом

```py
from itertools import compress

def is_unique(text):
    c_items = text.lower().split()
    for idx in range(len(c_items)):
        yield c_items[idx] not in c_items[:idx]

print(
    ' '.join(
        compress(txt_orig.split(), is_unique(txt_orig))
        
    )
)
```